# Replace letters in a string without space

Tags: java

My question is how I can change many letters in a string respectively? I mean every letter changed to another one for example change (A to G, B to H, C to X, D to Y, G to A)
for example:

I did this but nothing happened

```
String test = "ACDGBBDDGG";
String outputText = test.replaceAll("ABCDG","GHXYA");

System.out.println(outputText);
```

The output should be

```
GXYAHHYYAA
```

Comment: You need to do the replacements separately.

Answer (score 4):

One possible method is to add the `char` and it's replacement to a `Map` and then "map" between the two like

```
Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('A', 'G');
map.put('B', 'H');
map.put('C', 'X');
map.put('D', 'Y');
map.put('G', 'A');

String test = "ACDGBBDDGG";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
    char o = map.containsKey(c) ? map.get(c) : c;
    sb.append(o);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Another possibility (although more complex in terms of run-time) would be to to use the corresponding character's index in a `String` like

```
String in = "ABCDG";
String out = "GHXYA";
String test = "ACDGBBDDGG";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
    int i = in.indexOf(c);
    char o = (i > -1) ? out.charAt(i) : c;
    sb.append(o);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Both output (the requested)

```
 GXYAHHYYAA
```

Comment: Since Java 8 we can use `map.getOrDefault(c, c);` instead of `map.containsKey(c) ? map.get(c) : c;`.

Comment: @Pshemo Nice. But, as you noted [`Map.getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) is new in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

try outputText = test.replaceAll("A","G").replaceAll("B","H").replaceAll("C","X") etc.

Comment: No. In your solution, A will be replaced by G, which will later be replaced back to A.

Comment: @Jason No, that is not so.

Comment: Actually it is, since the last mapping would be G back to A.

Comment: I think @Jason you mean if I went all the way to the end, where the last one is G, so yes. It would fail for that particular example. I suppose you could solve that by putting them in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering but the output is AXYAHHYYAA

Comment: @DamonSmith No, you can't, because there's a cycle.  The only way you can deal with a cycle is with a dummy character: `test.replaceAll("A","*").replaceAll("G","A").replaceAll("*","G")`.  That's one reason why this method of doing translation is a poor approach--it may also be inefficient compared to setting up a translation table.

Comment: Also true. I actually can't believe I waded in on this question now. Sometimes you just see a newbie flailing and think you can knock it out quickly.

Comment: @ajb, I am afraid that `*` cannot be used, as this is a special character in regex.

Comment: @PhamTrung OK, the last should be `replaceAll("\\*","G")`.  Forgot that `replaceAll` takes a regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8:

```
String fromChars = "ABCDG";
String toChars = "GHXYA";
String test = "ACDGBBDDGG";

test.chars().forEach(ch->System.out.print(toChars.charAt(fromChars.indexOf(ch))));
```

You could alternatively collect the results and turn it into a String.